# Dynamic class-loading from specific folder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a requirement where i have to dynamically load java program based on the input. All java class files are placed in folder : C://Users/me/workspace/File/bin/Encrypt/.
there are 3 class files: Class1.class, Class2.class, Class3.class in this folder

To pick them up in runtime i am using below code:

```
  package First;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.net.URLClassLoader;

  public class Main 
  {

public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Say Class.class is the input file to be picked up.
    String abc = "Class1.class";    

   try { 
  File file = new File("C:\\Users\\me\\workspace\\File\\bin\\Encrypt"); 

    //convert the file to URL format
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL(); 
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url}; 

       //load this folder into Class loader
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls); 
    Class  cls = cl.loadClass(abc);

    System.out.println("cls.getName() = " + cls.getName());

    cls.encrypt();              

            } 
        catch ( ClassNotFoundException | MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
   }
```

I am facing below issues here:

1. The above code shows the error:  .NoClassDefFoundError: Class1?? 
   have used all types of - / ,\ ,//,\ in the path.
2. How can i call a method sum() in Class1  file  ??

Comment: Google Java Reflection API

Comment: This question is not related with javascript. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have `...\bin\Encrypt` is the folder where you classes are i would bet the package for your classes is `Encrypt`. in this case `abc` should be

```
String abc = "Enrcypt.Class1";
```

if the classes are in the default package which means they have no package declaration than use

```
String abc = "Class1";
```

note also that there is no need for the extension `.class` in the name of the class.

To call the a method of class loaded this way you should refer to [java refelction api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

first get a [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) object from [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) `cl` using [getMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

than use that method object's method [invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to call the function. you'll need to provide an instance of the Class dynamically loaded if the the method to call is not static, if it is static just pass null.